# aws route 53 MX Email server configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, mail-server, mx-record

I am trying to setup an email server using an EC2 instance(postfix)
I am trying to understand the value "10 mailserver.domainame.com".

does it mean I must do "hostname mailserver.domainame.com" on my email server? which means having mailserver.domainame.com as the  hostname?
what about the number "10"?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

10 is the "cost" of the mail exchanger. If you had a primary and a backup, you'd set the backup as a higher value, such as 20... so that servers trying to deliver mail to your domain would try the "lowest cost" (10) before the higher cost (20) server, and only use the 20 machine if they found the 10 machine inaccessible.  The number 10 is arbitrary.  It could be 5 or 0 or 17.  It has no real meaning if you only have one mail exchanger, but is still required.

You do not need to set the internal hostname of the machine at mailserver.example.com.  Nobody really sees or cares about that except you.  As long as you have a DNS `A` record for mailserver.example.com that returns the correct IP address, that is sufficient for MX configuration.